# Why is it linear time to traverse a list?

Tags: pointers, linked-list, time-complexity

Everyone knows that a list of length n can be traversed in O(n) time. This is since each step from one element of the list to the next is assumed done in O(1) time. If I know that the longest list that I ever need to store has length at most 4, then I would arrange, if I could, that every element gets stored in a register with one of the 2-bit addresses 00, 01, 10, or 11. Then the task of reading off the correct address and getting there requires knowing only few bits.
However, I keep thinking that if a list has something like a length of 2^100, then the use of pointers is slowed down. It appears that to distinguish the registers of two different elements of the list, the processor first has to digest 100 bits of address information before it knows which register to process next. Which would make each step have time demand more like Theta(log n), and the complete traversal a time requirement of O(nlog(n)).

Comment: It's normally an implicit assumption in such calculations that operations like accessing an arbitrary memory address are O(1).  In other words, if you are using lists of length 2^100, then you are doing it on a 128-bit CPU or thereabouts.

Comment: But I think the point is that when we upgrade the computer to solve a larger problem, then the O(1) on the new computer is larger than the O(1) on the original one. It is not clearly in accordance with our usual Turing Machine paradigm of complexity, which requires that all possible inputs have to be treated by the exact same algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are totally right. If someone says that traversing a list if O(n), it is based on the assumption that you can get from one element to the next in constant time. If you change these assumptions, you may get a different time complexity.

When people state a time complexity for an algorithm and use it for discussing executions on real computers, the following fact is usually glossed over:

*On a real physical computer, the number of different possible inputs is always finite, so a computer actually is a finite state machine (rather than a Turing Machine), and every algorithm has complexity O(1), strictly speaking (with a possibly rather large constant factor!). But we extrapolate this finite state machine to reason about its behaviour as if it weren't finite.*

In your example, the finite number of possible inputs for the list traversal algorithm is (in reality) bounded by the word length of the CPU (e.g. 64 bit), and you cannot have lists of length 2^100 (with the usual pointer-based algorithm). So strictly speaking, the complexity for traversing a list on a 64-bit CPU is O(1), but it *behaves like* O(n) within the range of possible inputs. The extrapolation breaks down for inputs outside of that range. That's the case for *all* algorithms that run on a real physical computer.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing different terms.
`n` refers to the number of elements in the list.
The time to travel from one element to the next is indeed usually considered to be O(1).
The example of non-trivial address resolution has no effect on the overall complexity as long as the address resolution is bounded by constant. So even if there are 2<sup>100</sup> elements in the list and the CPU has to perform several additional operations to retrieve the next element, it will still take O(1) to get to it, just with a slightly bigger constant. The complexity will be affected only if the retrieval depends somehow on the total number of elements in the list, which would be pretty awkward scenario. Possible, but awkward. Consider, for example, that the next element address isn't given by the next pointer, but encrypted at some memory location, and in order to retrieve it you need to apply the decryption algorithm `k` times, when `k` is the length of the list up to the current element. In this example the price for a single hop will indeed depend on the list length and the total complexity will increase.

Note: The assumption here is that the physical computer has no memory limit (otherwise it makes no sense to talk about complexity at all, since all algorithms will take O(1) time)

Comment: But in a sense, the OP is right: if you assume that your computer has no memory limit, it is unreasonable to assume that following a pointer is O(1) - rather, it would be O(log N). So the underlying assumption is that the computer has limited memory and a limited word length, say 64 bits. The problem is rather that in that case you can't have a pointer-based list with 2^100. If you implemented list traversal on a 64-bit computer supporting list lengths > 2^64 (not with simple pointers), you indeed can't do better than O(N log N), as the OP correctly stated.

Comment: @MoB. Why do you say that following a pointer is O(logN)? The OP used 2^100 as an address that can't be directly accessed by a computer (I assume he references 32/64-bit architectures). I agree about it when the memory is unlimited but the question doesn't seem to be stated this way (2^100 isn't unlimited even if it's not directly addressable by 64-bit arch).

Comment: What I mean is that following an address (not a "pointer" in the usual sense) of *unbounded* length is O(log N) where N is the address since you need to at least parse the address. So even on a 64-bit computer you could implement list traversal with (virtually) unbounded list lengths in O(N log N) assuming the list is stored on a device with random access (e.g. a system of hard disks). Of course, if we assume that lists can always be stored contiguously, we can do it in O(N). It all depends on your assumptions.

Comment: @MoB. That's exactly what I'm saying - the complexity will increase only if memory is unlimited thus requiring additional n-dependent computation to access an address. Architecture plays no role here - even if the address is out of arch support scope, if it's limited, it can still be accessed in O(1). BTW, linked list normally assumes non-contiguous storage. For contiguous storage each element can be accessed in O(1)*O(address deduction).

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername The situation explained by the OP may not be realistic but your assumption "as long as the address resolution is bounded by constant" is not correct in the OP context, as explained by MO B. If you assume a limited register size with unbounded address size you may have an address resolution that is affected by the total number of elements in the list.

Comment: @Ekeko Why both of you keep referring to unbounded address size? I believe I stated it clearly that I'm talking about *bounded* address size. As I believe the OP did by giving an explicit example with 2^100. Any size, as long as it is *bounded*, and regardless of the underlying architecture, instantly reduces the address resolution to O(1).

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I refer to unbounded address size because I believe this is what the OP is referring to. 2^100 is an example that seems to suggest that (some size that was not accounted for) and is in line with the OP's considerations about complexity.

Comment: @Ekeko There is no sense to give an example of something *finite* to demonstrate something *infinite*.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I don't know what you need to hear. It makes sense if we understand it. And we do. Maybe you don't. It's the OP way of saying, whatever the size of the address, he can always think of something bigger. I am a bit impressed that you don't get it, I don't have the impression it's complicated.

Comment: Well, it can be summarized this way: an OP asked a question with fundamentally wrong premise, you *assumed* to understand what he really meant and answered accordingly. Now I don't argue that he might indeed meant to ask that - however, I remind you that this isn't a private answering site but a site which targets to benefit all users, not just the one who asked the specific question. I don't see how providing an answer that might match the intent but completely incorrect otherwise, serves this purpose. Anyway, let's finish this conversation